# How I can debug MongoDB slow chunk migration?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to move chunk inside the cluster:

```
mongos>db.adminCommand({ moveChunk: "db.col", find: {_id: ObjectId("58171b29b9b4ebfb3e8b4e42")}, to: "shard_v2"});
```

> { "millis" : 428681, "ok" : 1 }

In log I see following record:

> 2016-11-08T20:27:05.972+0300 I SHARDING [conn27] moveChunk migrate
>   commit accepted by TO-shard: { active: false, ns: "db.col", from:
>   "host:27017", min: { _id: ObjectId('58171b29b9b4ebfb3e8b4e42') }, max:
>   { _id: ObjectId('58171f29b9b4eb31408b4b4c') }, shardKeyPattern: { _id:
>   1.0 }, state: "done", cc, ok: 1.0 }

So I have 23MB of data migrated in 430 sec. It is really slow.

I've uploaded a sample file to "host" and it was uploaded extremely fast (7-8MB per sec), so I do not think it is disk or network issue (cluster also does not have any load (no active queries)). What else I can check to improve chunk migration perfomance?

Answer (score 1):

The performance most certainly is not limited by your setup. It may be MongoDbs migration policy that tries not to effect the normal database tasks.

There is a great answer on this issue on DBA stack exchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81545/mongodb-shard-chunk-migration-500gb-takes-13-days-is-this-slow-or-normal

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean, when you say "normal database tasks" ?

Comment: I mean queries, inserts, updates and so on performed by actual users on the database. In contrast to chunk migration which is more an internal task of MongoDB.

Comment: As I sad, cluster does not have any load, so no queries were executed during chunk migration.

Comment: It will still not migrate with full velocity to not effect *potential* operations as far as i know. It is definitely a had question why it is that slow in your case. If the posted link isn't of much help you might want to have a look at Percona. They have some excellent experts on MongoDB and also some good blog posts.